# handle empty date in elasticsearch dynamically

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, kibana

I have below dynamic mapping template.

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
   "dynamic_templates": [
     {
       "objects": {
         "match_mapping_type": "object",
         "mapping": {
           "type": "nested"
         }
       }
     }
   ],
   "dynamic_date_formats": ["yyyy-MM-dd" , "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]
 }
}
```

Only problem is when I am having empty date it is throwing error. I just want to ignore empty dates. My data having multiple date fields hence don't want to do mapping for each date fields.

Below is the error I am getting:

org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopRemoteException: illegal_argument_exception: mapper [pb_bureau.applications.accounts.dateclosed] of different type, current_type [text], merged_type [date]
    {"index":{"_id":"02ade9b5-1ca5-4006-ab06-9c96439e7d02"}}

below date we are inserting: blank field is null value of date

```
select date1, date2 from cbl_application_credit_report_account ;
    2014-11-14
    2018-03-31
2012-07-27  2012-07-23
    2015-11-30
2017-08-04  2016-05-13
```

below is mapping which I am applying:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
   "dynamic_templates": [
     {
       "objects": {
         "match_mapping_type": "object",
         "mapping": {
           "type": "nested"
         }
       }
     },
     {
        "dates_ignore_malformed": {
          "path_match": "*",
          "match_mapping_type": "date",
          "mapping": {
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd||yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
            "ignore_malformed": true
          }
        }
      }
   ],
   "dynamic_date_formats": ["yyyy-MM-dd" , "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]
 }
}
```

Is there any way in the dynamic mapping to ignore empty dates?

Comment: Do you date fields share a consistent naming? i.e. do they all end with `Date` or `_date`, etc ?

Answer (score 0):

Mapping:

```
PUT my_index4
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "objects": {
          "match_mapping_type": "object",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "nested"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "dates_ignore_malformed": {
          "path_match": "*",
          "match_mapping_type": "date",
          "mapping": {
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd||yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ---> date format on which to be applied ,
            "ignore_malformed": true ---> Ignores if field s malformed
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "dynamic_date_formats": [
      "yyyy-MM-dd",
      "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    ]
  }
}
```

Data:

```
POST my_index4/_doc
{
  "date":"2019-01-01 04:30:22",
   "Id":1
}

POST my_index4/_doc
{
  "name":2,
  "date":"2019-01-01"
}

POST my_index4/_doc
{
  "name":2,
  "date":""
}
```

Query:

```
GET my_index4/_search
```

Result:

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_index4",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "NT5XSG0BbzgYofLxTDZ_",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "date" : "2019-01-01 04:30:22",
          "Id" : 1
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "my_index4",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Nj5XSG0BbzgYofLxUTaT",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : 2,
          "date" : "2019-01-01"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "my_index4",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Nz5XSG0BbzgYofLxWDYi",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_ignored" : [
          "date"
        ],
        "_source" : {
          "name" : 2,
          "date" : ""
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried the same thing. I am getting the same error. Because the thing is if I got the empty date in the first row and the date is in the second row. It throws an error. I have updated my question with error message.

Comment: I am not able to replicate it. Is "mapping": {   "format": "yyyy-MM-dd||yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" same as dynamic_date_formats and is ignore_malformed set to true. Can you check the new mapping and post the data you are trying to enter

Comment: I have updated my question for your reference. data is like somewhere date is empty somewhere is not. May be I am wrong, but es is deciding the data type on the basis of 1st value of column.

Comment: I tried your posted mapping with data you  below data. It is not giving me error. Can you check mapping using GET my_index6/_mapping and verify if recent mapping is getting applied.  POST my_index6/_doc
{
  "date":"2014-11-14",
  "date1":"2014-11-14"
}

post my_index6/_doc
{
   "date":"2018-03-31"
}

post my_index6/_doc
{
  "Id":3
}

Comment: you are right. I am not getting error for your data either. But only concern if I insert this data "POST my_index/_doc {"name":2,"date":"}" for the first time. Data type of column 'date' becomes 'text' datatype. and second time if insert data with some value if will go as text type only.

Comment: Mapping for a field is created when first record is entered and same is used further.If first record is empty you will have to go with what @Val has said. There must be a pattern in field name(some common text)  and you need to use match parameter in dynamic template (uses a pattern to match on the field name)